Why are housewives living on the same street as Don Draper so obsessed with Helen's long walks?
In the TV show, Mad Men, a divorced woman, Helen Bishop, lives on the same street as Don Draper and his wife, Betty Draper.
On several occasions, other housewives talk about how Helen Bishop has "long walks" and how her long walking is pathetic and selfish.
One occasion is in Season 1, Episode 7, "Red in the Face." Betty slaps Helen in the face after their unpleasant encounter in a produce store. Later, one woman comes and visits Betty, and they have a discussion about the slapping incident. They start having a conversation about Betty's pathetic job, long walks, and being selfish.
Logically, I cannot see why a woman having long walks can be interpreted as pathetic or selfish.
Given that this TV show is set in the 1960s in New York, why would people think this way?

Its hard to see why 'long walks' are a particular concern. Reading the transcript it is the job at the jewelry shop that is pathetic, not the walks.

I think I'd have to re-watch the episode to be sure - but she's an attractive divorcee and they are all concerned about their husbands.  Talk of selfishness probably relates to her putting herself ahead of husband and family, in an era when divorce was less common.

They are just enjoying trashing her - pouring scorn on her situation, anything that sets her apart from them - having to work, taking long walks rather than just making her house nice for her husband.

The "selfishness" is because Helen is a strong independent woman who does what she wants to do and can do it alone, and the "patheticness" is because she is misunderstood and judged based on prejudice and inhibition.
In a time when women are supposed to act or even be a certain way, taking walks alone as a woman is socially unconventional. The walks being explicitly long, and the fact that Helen Bishop is a divorcée, makes this even more remarkable and suspicious ("where does she even go?!").
That her job is being frowned upon is because women in their social class at the time rarely took up a job after they got married. I think Francine tells Betty Helen's job is pathetic simply because it is a job.
As far as I can remember, and it being a motif that especially Betty embodies, the show in all of this hints at the idea that the women gossiping, being fascinated by the abnormal behaviour of this unconventional woman, find it difficult to deal with their feelings of envy for this liberated life style, and, as they have to maintain their social semblance, channel this through begrudging or outright rejecting it.
In the scene you speak of, when Betty's friend Francine meets up with her after the incident in the supermarket, they have this dialogue:

F: I think they'll be glad to know you're not a marshmallow.
B: Do people think I'm weak?
F: No. It's just you're so sweet and perfect.
B: I'm not.
F: Well, it does seem that way.

This clearly emphasizes that dichotomy between appearance/perception and reality.

For clarity: the TV show is set around New York, because the ad agency is based there - the Drapers live in Ossining.

Well explained.  Anything unconventional which sets her apart from them is being frowned upon.  The scene in question, they are going over a list of barely connected complaints and insults.
